# Markdown + Pandoc + Template - PDF

Tags: luatex, pandoc, markdown

I am currently doing a thesis, so I have to add various things from university (logo, ..).
The following code, I try to add a logo on my titlepage, I use the template eisvogel (https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/blob/master/README.md) based on the documentation, I must proceed as follows:

```
---
resource-path=.: src
titlepage: true
titlepage-logo: Logo.png
...
```

But,

```
pandoc thesis.md -o thesis1.pdf --template=eisvogel --standalone --pdf-engine=lualatex
Error producing PDF.
! Package luatex.def Error: File
`Logo.png' not found: using draft setting.
l.289 ...raphics[width=35mm, left{Logo.png}
```

I tried to put the photo in the root of my .md, in a src file, in the root of pandoc (C:\Users\zek0l\AppData\Roaming\pandoc) and in a sub-folder, nothing works

Minimal for @samcarter

```
---
title: "testing"
author: "tester"
date: "now"
titlepage: true
titlepage-logo: "Logo.png"
...

aaaaaa
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example instead of just a fragment of an header?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz edited

Comment: That code does not produce a pdf document

Comment: It does if you edit the base command: pandoc test.md -o test.pdf --template=eisvogel --standalone --pdf-engine=lualatex

Comment: Try with `header-includes: \graphicspath{{insert path to the folder which contains your Logo.png file}}` in your header

Comment: From the docs: "path to an image that will be displayed on the title page. The path is always relative to where pandoc is executed. The option --resource-path has no effect."

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz same error.. :(
DG' I tried to put in C:\Users\zek0l\AppData\Roaming\pandoc yeah

Comment: Did you read [this advice](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/blob/master/README.md#latex-error-cannot-find-image-file) from the docs you linked above?